# Django-import-export is not getting imported in admin.py

Tags: django, django-import-export

I am trying to use django-import-export library to provide excel data upload action in the admin panel.

I have done following

```
pip install django-import-export
```

Have added it to installed apps

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
...
'import_export',)
```

Have collected staticfiles

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

However now when I am trying to import import_export in admin.py, It is showing an error that module is not found.

[Image of admin.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLDI4.png)

I have checked I am in same virtual environment.

PIP freeze shows that the module django-import-export is installed in the virtual environment.

[PIP Freeze image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzFFr.png)

Can someone help with what I am doing wrong here

Answer (score 0):

Does the error come from inside an IDE such as PyCharm?  If so, you may have to adjust the project settings to ensure that the correct virtualenv is picked up.

You can try to follow the steps to install the [example app](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#example-app) to verify that works before installing into your own project.